# Using boost::flyweight<T> inside struct T {} (ie, recursive flyweights)

Tags: boost, flyweight-pattern

I'm trying to define an immutable file-path value type, taking advantage of boost::flyweight to share path components. Something like this:

```
struct filepath_data;
typedef boost::flyweight<filepath_data> filepath;
struct filepath_data {
    boost::optional<filepath> parent;
    std::string name;
};
```

Of course, this looks like a recursive structure, but `boost::flyweight<T>` doesn't actually (itself) contain a copy of `T`, just a handle to a `T` which can be looked up in the appropriate holder, so I think this structure should work.

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile, because when g++ hits the typedef it complains that filepath_data is incomplete.

So, the question is, can I make use of the flexibility and more advanced template arguments for `boost::flyweight<>` to make this structure work, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example](http://www.boost.org/libs/flyweight/example/composite.cpp) shows how to combine Boost.Flyweight with a recursive data structure using [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html) and [`boost::recursive_wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-wrapper). Maybe you can use a similar approach for your problem.